# How to a loop through an incoming multi-part formdata request array using Ruby on Rails?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, object, multipartform-data

I am receiving a formdata request that is an array of objects (object contains file data). The request leaving the browser looks like the below image

[image: Request leaving the browser]

I understand why it is being read by rails as objects. An example of the parameters being received by rails is here.

```
{"id"=>"1",
 "user_id"=>"8",
 "contact_phone"=>"07969363020",
 "about"=>"I am a job seeker",
 "trade_ids"=>{"0"=>"1"},
 "qualification_ids"=>
  {"0"=>
    {"expiry_date"=>"2023-01-27T00:00:00.000Z",
     "path"=>
      #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fed38c2acb8
       @content_type="image/png",
       @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"qualification_ids[0][path]\"; filename=\"facebook.png\"\r\n" + "Content-Type: image/png\r\n",
       @original_filename="facebook.png",
       @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/sp/fc_js2cx5lgdmbdqtbng06640000gn/T/RackMultipart20230126-45759-zm83xm.png>>,
     "id"=>"1",
     "name"=>"CSCS Green Labourer",
     "created_at"=>"2023-01-02T19:49:24.941Z",
     "updated_at"=>"2023-01-02T19:49:24.941Z",
     "temp_path"=>"blob:http://localhost:3000/e83b72ca-f7d9-4cb3-be63-906a11c05357"}}}
```

I would however like to loop through the qualification_ids as if they were an array.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `each_value` and `each_key` methods on Ruby hashes, depending on what you want to iterate through.

Here is an example of a much shorter form to illustrate the usage.

```rb
qualification_ids = {"0": {"id": "1"}}

qualification_ids.each_value{|value| puts value}
=> {:id=>"1"}

qualification_ids.each_key{|key| puts key}
=> 0

qualification_ids.each_value{|a| puts a[:id]}
=> 1
```

I hope this helps :-)